# Connecting an ATI GPU to my old P5S800-VM AsusTek motherboard

Tags: cpu, motherboard, gpu

I have an old computer lying around, and decided to put it to use (bitcoin mining). Problem is, I need to connect a GPU to it in order to do bitcoin mining at a high level. My old computer has the AsusTek computer inc. P5S800-VM motherboard, with Intel Pentium 4 built in. Link:
http://www.asus.com/Motherboard/P5S800VM/

Is it possible to hook this motherboard up with an ATI GPU? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That board has four expansion slots: 3x PCI and 1xAGP. It has **no** modern PCIe slots.

This means you would need a very old card, one which is unlikely to do much good for bitmining.

> Is it possible to hook this motherboard up with an ATI GPU?
>   If so, how can i do it?

Locate a proper PCI or AGP card (Not a PCIe card). You can find these for about £4 on ebay. Then plug the card in the matching connector. Done.

<sup>Nitpick: It does not have a pentium-IV build in.</sup>